# How do I read 1 dimensional data from a text file into a 1D array? [Python]

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a text file DATALOG1.TXT with values from 0 to 1023, pertaining to a signal. The file  has one value per row, all values stored in a column. Here is an example of how the first values are stored in the file:

```
0
0
576
0
643
60
0
1012
0
455
69
0
1023
0
258
```

I have the following code, which outputs for the "magnitude" only values between 0 to 9, as if normalized. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


values = [] #array to be filled

#reading data from the file into the array
f = open('DATALOG1.TXT', 'r')
for line in f:
    values.append(line[0])

#creating another array of the same size to plot against
time = np.arange(0, len(values), 1)

plt.bar(time, values, color='g', label='File Data')
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Magnitude', fontdsize=12)
plt.title('Magnitude changes', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Why is the output between 0 and 9 as opposed to showing the values in the text file (between 0 and 1023)?

Comment: What specifically is not working?  This is not a code-writing, code-testing, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.  See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: My bad. Removed the image and added the example of how values (from the source text file) are stored in the question. Also rephrased the question at the end to be more clear. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking `line[0]` you just append the first  character of each line to the list.

Since you already use numpy, you can use `genfromtxt` to load the data file.

Your code would become:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


values = [] #array to be filled

#reading data from the file into the array
values = np.genfromtxt('DATALOG1.TXT')


#creating another array of the same size to plot against
time = np.arange(0, len(values), 1)

plt.bar(time, values, color='g', label='File Data')
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Magnitude changes', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```py
for line in f:
    values.append(line[0])
```

What you append is the first character of each line to your list `values`. The list `values` contains the entire line including line endings. If you were to use

```py
for line in f:
    values.append(line.strip())
```

you should be a lot closer to your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read the complete file, split the values per newline character `\n` (i used [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for that) and to convert strings to integers. Also, if you use `range` instead of numpys `arange` you can avoid using numpy at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#reading data from the file into the array
data = open('DATALOG1.TXT', 'r').read()
values = [int(f) for f in data.split("\n")]
time = range(len(values))

plt.bar(time, values, color='g', label='File Data')
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Magnitude', fontdsize=12)
plt.title('Magnitude changes', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```